# how to edit/delete external css link in head

Tags: magento-1.7, link, head

I've just recently updated my SSL certificate but now my site shows a mixed content warning:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ecosaver.com/' was loaded over
HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:300,400,600'. This request
has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

So it seems I just need to edit (or last resort delete) that particular style sheet link in my `<head>`. I've tried  `<action method="removeItem">` in local.xml to no avail. I may be using the wrong syntax or maybe I'm completely off and doing something else wrong. I've just started with Magento so still trying to get the hang of it. I'm using Magento V. 1.7.0.2 Thanks very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `https` to the call of the Google font API URL or like it said in this explanation you can remove URL protocol : http://www.amixa.com/blog/2012/06/06/how-to-use-google-fonts-under-both-ssl-and-non-ssl-without-ssl-insecure-messages/

**Solution 1**
call `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

**Solution 2** (*preferred solution*)
call `<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

---

Like it said in the post **solution 2** is the better way to do it because you do not to worry anymore about that.

Comment: Solution 2 is the right approach

Comment: Yes I did not precise it in my answer because it is in the link but I will do it again ;)